# PHP file for Cron job runs automatically randomly

Tags: php, email, cron

I've a PHP based app. We've to run a PHP file (say xyz.php) once daily to send emails. We use Cron job in cPanel to run that file everyday in the morning. I've setup my email as cron email so that I get notified every time the cron job is executed. It runs perfectly in the morning - sends the data which is required correctly and I also get notified via email every morning that cron job executed successfully.

That PHP file's URL (abc.com/xyz.php) if entered in browser manually will also send emails.

Now coming to the problem part - The email IDs in the PHP file start getting emails at random times and sometimes 30-40 emails a day. The emails are incomplete and incorrect. I don't get any notification email that cron job has executed. So, my guess is the PHP file is accessed by something which triggers the emails. I've checked access logs in the cPanel but there's nothing in there.

The app is hosted on Hostgator, if that helps.

Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some exmplanations:

- You may have included the file in some code,
- Someone is accessing the file (but you outed that)
- There may be another cron job defined (it may happend if for some reason two jobs were created or someone created it by other panels, by hand with different times) - like for testing.
- Someone may execute it manually

  1. you you must find out yourself.
  2. block it by password or totally with .htaccess
  3. check your cron settings (also for each user crontable)
  4. check logs

Also - WRITE some code into you php file that will log HOW and WHEN it was executed - that will allow you to further test what is happening.

Comment: 1. No, not included in code.
2. Yes, nothing shows in logs.
3. No other cron job defined.
4. If someone executes it then it should show in logs or no?
5. I'll write the code to write the log. Thanks. Will update once I find anything with this.

Comment: No, if you dont log executions directly in the file code - its execution may not be logged anywhere.

Comment: If i make something that is executed by cron i always do two things:

1. Write locks inside (sometimes i have crons that executed each minute, but are forbided to run more than one copy at time) - i use fopen with wrting permissions. If files open - im the one working copy. If not - other copy is working and im off.

Comment: 2. Write many logs (they can be turned of by using one superglobal like: $_SERVER['debug']=false/true;  (yea i dont mind that for this purpose). I log times of execution, progress of work and so on (to files, db - what you think is best for this the problem).

Comment: 3. I try to make code that can be killed, then executed once more - and it will resume working from place it stopped (or near it).
Sorry for making 3 comments - i found character limit;P

Comment: Thanks! Stopped the email bombing now. Keeping fingers crossed. :)

Answer (score 1):

this may happen when you have `include` your `abc.com/xyz.php` on some other `php` files , which get executed when the `php` pages is  called via browser and some part of form get executed, also you wont get mail notofications for this type of exectutions

Comment: No, it's not included in any other PHP file of our application. However, other PHP files are included in this particular (xyz.php) file.

Comment: then some one will executing the file via browser ,prevent running the file via browser